# Dialog on CKEDITOR

Tags: angular, ckeditor5, ckeditor4.x

On version 4 of ckeditor there was the possibility to display a dialog box when creating a custom plugin, but on version 5 it is not possible ?

Ckeditor v4

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add('', function (editor) {
  var dialog = {
  };
  return dialog;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no UI component for dialog box in ckeditor 5 and they [don't plan](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-design/issues/179) to create any.

It's recommended to use [contextual 'balloons'](https://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-5-v12.2.0-with-mobile-friendly-comments-mode/) instead.